# NodeJS + AngularJS $http get

Tags: angularjs

I am using Nodejs and AngularJS and i am having a problem with filling a table in the front-end from a generated JSON file.

I have the below ejs file:

```
<% include layout %>

<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class= "panel-title"> <%=title %></h3>

</div>

<br>

<div
        data-ng-app="projectionsModule"
        data-ng-controller="projectionsController">

<div class="container">
    <%include projectionsGrid%>
</div>

</div>


<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../javascripts/app/projections/projectionsModule.js">       </script>
<script src="../../javascripts/app/projections/projectionsService.js"></script>
<script src="../../javascripts/app/projections/projectionsController.js"></script>
```

and the projectionsGrid.ejs  as of below:

```
<table
      data-ng-show="projections.length > 0"
      class='table table-striped table-hover'
>

    <tr class="success">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-ng-repeat="projection in projections">
    <td>{{projection.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{projection.Age}}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

The controller is the following:

```
angular.module("projectionsModule")
.controller("projectionsController", projectionsController);

projectionsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'projectionsService'];

function projectionsController($scope, projectionsService) {

  //  $scope.projections = [];


    getAllProjections();


    function getAllProjections() {
        projectionsService.getAllProjections().
            success(function (response) {
                $scope.projections = response.projections;
                alert(response.projections);
               // console.log(response.projections[0]);

            })
    }
}
```

and the Service :

```
angular.module("projectionsModule")
.factory("projectionsService", projectionsService);

projectionsService.$inject = ['$http'];

function projectionsService($http) {

    return {

        getAllProjections : function () {
            return $http.get('/getAllProjections');
        }
    };
}
```

It seems that the

```
projectionsService.getAllProjections().
            success(function (response) {
                $scope.projections = response.projections;
```

does not work. 
In the browser with Inspect all files are loaded correctly.

The json file is the below:

```
{
      "projections": [
        {
          "name": "Alex",
          "age": "18"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The printscreen i get when i run it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABeTo.png)

Could someone please help mew cause i really do not know what else to do.

Thank you.

Print screen with error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPXCY.png)

Comment: Debug it and put breakpoint inside success(). Does breakpoint get hit?

Comment: If you change `success()` to `then()` does it work? success() is similar to then() but it is deprecated now.

Comment: With then() it returns 'undefined' in the alert... I cannot debug it that is why i had the alert and as it is now it returns 'Object'... Moreover when i Inspect Code the page it loads all the files that are needed including the  /getAllProjections.

Comment: Make sure that the endpoint that you request does return response. What do you mean you can not debug?

Comment: It does return a response meaning that when i hit http://localhost:1337/getAllProjections i get the json file. When i say i cannot debug i mean that it passed the debugger without any error

Comment: I have also added a print screen

Comment: See my answer and if it fits you.

Comment: If alert shown then it means then() is successfully execute the function. Are you sure you put the breakpoint correctly?

Comment: About your second problem, could you post the error you get once the pending request is completed ? Or does it never get completed ?

Comment: After 6 mins of waiting it fails. The status in Network is failed.

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of that error please ?

Comment: I added the error print screen

Comment: I guess your method fetches data from database. Could you try to send a simple JSON object instead ? This way, we will see if it's database related, or server related.

Comment: You are right... when I sent a simple json file i did not have this problem no matter how many times i refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [related plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RNb5iL4WXWchMtDxS4DL?p=preview).

You are using promises wrong. If you need explanation, ask me in a comment.

```
// Mandatory code for plunkr link
```

In your case, instead of returning an object, just make a `$http` call and delete the timeout. I'll let you do it, but if you need help, feel free to ask.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT** you forgot to include `$http` as a dependency. You can also use `$http.get`, which is faster and (for me at least) easier to understand ([see the documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get))

```
angular.module("projectionsModule")
    .factory("projectionsService", function($q, $http) { 
        return { 
            projectionFunction: projectionFunction 
        } 

        function projectionFunction() { 
            return $http.get('127.0.0.1:1337/getAllProjections', {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION** You need to use `$q` to use promises. Take a look into it, you will use it very often with your http requests. Your function should look like this :

```
angular.module("projectionsModule")
    .factory("projectionsService", function($q, $http) { 
        return { 
            projectionFunction: projectionFunction 
        } 

        function projectionFunction() { 
            var defer = $q.defer();

            $http.get('127.0.0.1:1337/getAllProjections', {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }).then(function(success) {
                defer.resolve(success);
            }, function(error) {
                defer.reject(error);
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }
    });
```

In your controller, you can then do something like that :

```
function getAllProjections() {
    projectionsService.projectionFunction().then(function(success) {
        $scope.projections = success.data.projections;
        // do an alert(success) to see what is in it !
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error.data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am really sorry for my ignorance but i am new to Angular. I have tried to modify the Service.js as of below : angular.module("projectionsModule")
.factory("projectionsService", function($q) {
    return {
        projectionFunction: projectionFunction
    }

    function projectionFunction() { 
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:1337/getAllProjections',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });}
}); but still table does not load the data

Comment: I still cannot get anything in the table ... I really do not know what else to do.. I got worn out..

Comment: Man, I thought you would give it a try and use `$q`by yourself ... I will give you the answer, but next time, try on your own. See my second edit.

Comment: Really thank you for you support. It worked. And please do not misunderstand me ... I had tried it and i was trying with http://127.0.0.1:1337/getAllProjections which was giving me the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." which i fixed. Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Could i please ask you something else if you know?? I hit refresh (F5) for many times and after exactly the tenth time the http.get request hangs with status 'Pending' and it does not respond unless i restart the server. Could you please help me if you know?

Comment: I actually never faced this issue. What are your servers logs and your console logs ? Maybe you should make a new post for it

Comment: I have attached in the initial question. Actually i have posted a new question but i got no response. If you have any idea as to what I have done most probably wrongly I would appreciate it.